# Export GMF RCP Application with Product Configuration

Tags: java, rcp, eclipse-gmf

How to export eclipse RCP Application to a eclipse Product?

I generate a GMF Editor with RCP, its fine to run with "Run as".
Now I want to export this with Eclipse Product Configuration,
do someone know, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new [Eclipse Product Configuration](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product%3F)

> File > New > Other > Plugin Development > Product Configuration